# 1D<>3D Array Indexing

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to flatten a 3D array to a 1D array in C# for use with Unity. I'm aware this has been asked A LOT - but all the answers I've found pertained to arrays organised by Z-axis, and I'd like mine arranged by Y-axis. There were some decent explanations on how to switch indices; I thought this would do that, but it appears not. Any help here would be great; I've resorted to storing an integer referring to each cell's 1D index in a 3D array for now so I can verify everything else works normally etc; but obviously that's no kind of a solution! Here's my code:

```
    public int VoxelToIndex( int x, int y, int z )
    {
        return x + ( z*worldSize.x ) + ( y*worldSize.x*worldSize.z );
    }

    public Vector3Int IndexToVoxel( int index )
    {
        Vector3Int voxel = Vector3Int.zero;
        voxel.x = index % worldSize.x;
        voxel.y = Mathf.FloorToInt( index / ( worldSize.x*worldSize.z ) );
        voxel.z = Mathf.FloorToInt( index / worldSize.x ) % worldSize.z;
        return voxel;
    }
```

Expected results are that it identifies the correct 1D index for the 3D index input (and vica-versa); but the reported index is always offset by some amount - the amount offset varies wildly.

Big thanks in advance to anyone who weighs in.

Comment: What are you actually asking here? Are these two functions not outputting the results you expect? If so, give examples of your input, expected output, and actual output. If that's not what you're asking then you need to clarify your question

Comment: Apologies! Forgot to mention the output - I've updated it now. Any thoughts?

Comment: The same code (without the Mathf.Floor, that's a Unity specific class) seems to be working fine in [this sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AjsHlH). When you say 'correct 1D index', you need to actually give a concrete example of what you expected and what you got

Comment: I'm gonna delete this I think, because having set up a full comparison of what I expect vs what I get it actually lines up perfectly. It even lines up perfectly with the contents of the integer array I've been using in its place. It's clear the problem isn't with this code; but given that this code outputs the same values as the integer array, I'm now very stumped :/ Thanks for your time though, I appreciate the confirmation.